# What are the superscript negative signs after the $E$ and $H$ in the equation for 'Wave impedance'?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, notation

The wave impedance is given by

${\displaystyle Z={E_{0}^{-}(x) \over H_{0}^{-}(x)}}$

where
${\displaystyle E_{0}^{-}(x)}$ is the electric field and ${\displaystyle H_{0}^{-}(x)} $ is the magnetic field, in phasor representation. The impedance is, in general, a complex number.

On Wikipedia's article, it mentions 'phasor representation', but I went through its phasor page, and could not find anything like it...

Do superscripted negative signs AFTER a constant or variable mean 'the opposite of' or 'negative'?

Answer (score 3):

Very often in a wave propagation analysis, superscript '+' indicates the fields associated with the wave propagating in the positive direction and superscript '-' indicates the fields associated with the wave propagating in the negative direction.

When calculating the impedance, you would take the ratio of the E and H fields for the wave travelling in one or the other direction, so that is likely the meaning here.